# Looping the array inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fetch the value from the JSON object. Below is the data. I am trying to loop all the array objects and get the value of

> Employee[].gradeDetails.objDetails[].sno

Below is the code I've so far:

```js
var Obj = {
  "Employee": [{
    "type": "grade A",
    "gradeDetails": {
      "objDetails": [{
        "sno": "100",
        "name": "",
        "desg": "writer",
        "salary": "1000000"
      }, {
        "sno": "200",
        "name": "",
        "desg": "developer",
        "salary": "1000"
      }, {
        "sno": "300",
        "name": "",
        "desg": "",
        "salary": "8000"
      }]
    }
  }]
}
var path = "Employee[].gradeDetails.objDetails[].sno";

var arrayPos = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2]
];
arrayPos.forEach(function(val) {
  var data = getField(Obj, path, val);
})

function getField(postObj, path, arrayPosition) {
  arrayPosition = arrayPosition.slice(Math.max(arrayPosition.length - 2, 0));
  var postObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postObj));
  var pathArray = path.split(".");
  pathArray.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key.indexOf("[]") != -1) {
      var position = 0;
      try {
        var flag = false;
        if (arrayPosition.length == 1) {
          flag = true;
        }
        if (arrayPosition.length > 1) {
          position = arrayPosition.shift();
        }
        var pos = 0;
        var arrOcc = -1;
        var occIndex = -1;
        while (pos != -1) {
          pos = path.indexOf("[]", occIndex + 1);
          arrOcc += 1;
          occIndex = pos;
        }
        if (arrOcc == 1) {
          position = arrayPosition[arrayPosition.length - 1];
          console.log("Postion" + position);
        }
        key = key.substring(0, key.indexOf("["));
        postObj = postObj[key];
        if (arrOcc == 2) {
          if (flag) {
            if (postObj.length == 2) {
              position = arrayPosition[arrayPosition.length - 1];
            }
          }
        }
        if (position == undefined) position = 0;
        postObj = postObj[position];
      } catch (e) {}
    } else {
      try {
        postObj = postObj[key];
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  });

  console.log("Result[" + arrayPosition + "]" + postObj)

  return postObj;
}
```

Since there are three array objects, I am expecting three different values of **sno** as below. Can someone help me in finding out what wrong I am doing in my code. Because I am getting always the result as 100.

```
Result[0]100
Result[1]200
Result[2]300
```

My full code is available in this link [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/6e8qz0kd/)

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, this line

```
        if (postObj.length == 2) { //should be 3 not 2
              position = arrayPosition[arrayPosition.length - 1];
        }
```

check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e8qz0kd/1/)

P.s.:the code is a bit "complex", could be more structure, this would help by debugging.

But if you are looking for a shorter Version, here this option is shorter(8 Line Solution), and should have the same function

```
function getField(postObj, path, arrayPosition) {

    // Replaces square brakets with the Index of the passed Array(plus a dot) . 
    var newPath = path.replace(/(\[\])/gi,function(){return "." + arrayPosition.shift();});
    //creates a list of property 'namens'
    var pathElements = newPath.split(".");
    var value = postObj;
    for(var x in pathElements){
        // In each step it goes deeper into the json Object
        value = value[pathElements[x]];
    }
    return value;
}
```

here in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgu1gp7a/)

**update:** just added same comments into the code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your code. But it seems to be taking time as you have not commented the code to show us what you are trying to do.. I re-implemented it with in a recursive way (error handling is not implemented). Hope this will help you...

```js
var Obj = {
    "Employee": [
        {
            "type": "grade A",
            "gradeDetails": {
                "objDetails": [
                    {
                        "sno": "100",
                        "name": "",
                        "desg": "writer",
                        "salary": "1000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "sno": "200",
                        "name": "",
                        "desg": "developer",
                        "salary": "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        "sno": "300",
                        "name": "",
                        "desg": "",
                        "salary": "8000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};

var path = "Employee[].gradeDetails.objDetails[].sno";
var arrayPos = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]];

arrayPos.forEach(function (val) {
    alert(getField(Obj, path, val));
});

function getField(obj, path, arrayPosition) {
    if (path == ""){
        return obj;
    }
 var property = path.split(".")[0];
    var nextPath = path.replace(property,"").replace(".","");
    var nextObj;
    var nextArrPos;
    if (property.indexOf("[]") != -1){
        nextObj = obj[property.replace("[]","")][arrayPosition[0]];
        nextArrPos = arrayPosition.slice(1);
    } else {
        nextObj = obj[property];
        nextArrPos = arrayPosition;
    }
 return getField(nextObj,nextPath,nextArrPos);
}
```

Comment: @plbsm Thanks for the response. But the same thing I want to make it work through my function.